# SqlBulkCopy issues

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, sqlbulkcopy

Is anyone aware of issues with using SqlBulkCopy when being executed from code on a SqlExpress database?

I have a full instance of SQL Server 2008 and also an instance of SQL Server 2008 Express.  The full instance installed on a server, and the express instance installed locally on a test machine.  Whenever I run my application (which uses the following code) using the Server Connection String it executes just fine and I can see the newly inserted rows and informational messages.  But whenever I run my application using the Local Sql Express connection string nothing happens and I get no messages, or table rows inserted.  This is a desktop application installed on the test machine (same machine that running Sql Express)

This really has me stumped because I've got it all in try catch blocks but no exception is being thrown. It just seems like it doesn't execute. Please advise! Thanks

Here is my code:

```
 public static bool BulkInsertReminders(DataTable dtReminders)
    {
        bool success = false;
        string sql = "user id=" + DBEntries.DBUser + ";password=" + DBEntries.DBPassword + ";server=" + DBEntries.DBHost + ";database=" + DBEntries.LocalDB + ";Encrypt=YES;TrustServerCertificate=true";
        MessageBox.Show("Insert Rows Count: " + dtReminders.Rows.Count);
        using (SqlConnection msSQL = new SqlConnection(sql))
        {
            SqlTransaction copy = null;
            SqlCommand commandRowCount = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + "dbo.reminders", msSQL);
            try
            {
                msSQL.Open();
                copy = msSQL.BeginTransaction();
                using (SqlBulkCopy load = new SqlBulkCopy(msSQL, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock, copy))
                {
                    load.BulkCopyTimeout = 15;
                    load.ColumnMappings.Add("reminder_id", "reminder_id");
                    load.ColumnMappings.Add("creation_date", "creation_date");
                    load.ColumnMappings.Add("created_by", "created_by");
                    load.ColumnMappings.Add("sent", "sent");
                    load.ColumnMappings.Add("sent_by", "sent_by");
                    load.ColumnMappings.Add("sent_date", "sent_date");
                    load.DestinationTableName = "dbo.reminders";
                    load.WriteToServer(dtReminders);
                    success = true;
                    commandRowCount.Transaction = copy;
                    int totalRows = Convert.ToInt32(commandRowCount.ExecuteScalar());
                    MessageBox.Show("New Table Row Count: " + totalRows + Environment.NewLine + "Rows Before Insert: " + (totalRows - dtReminders.Rows.Count));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error - Issues adding reminders information to database.", "Contact Support");
                email err = new email();
                err.sendErrorEmail(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name.ToString() + "." + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.ToString(), exc.Message, exc.Data, exc.StackTrace);
                success = false;
                copy.Rollback();
            }

        }
        return success;
    }
```

Comment: Try stepping through your code in debugger

Comment: So my development machine is different than the test environment (because i'm not QA) but I have connected up to the test machine from my PC and run through code. It looks to be executing from the dev pc just fine. Only when everything runs on the test machine connected to SQL Express do I see issues

Comment: Connect to the test machine SQL Express from your machine if you can. If you can't and if you can't figure out the problem otherwise add some logging code in, so you can see what is executed and what is not.

Comment: Barked up the wrong tree on this one. Turned out to be a replication Insert/Triggers problem. That was the difference between the server and the test machine. Although I will note that BulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers had no effect. I had to use "sp_addtabletocontents @tablename" to get this working.

Comment: @Encryption, if you post an answer explaining how to detect and fix this problem, I will vote it up.